# success page template file not called : M2

Tags: magento2, order-success-page

After M2 upgrade  `success.phtml` template file not called at order success page.

while `onepage.phtml` file is called at onepage checkout page.

Both file location is same but still `success.phtml` file not called:

> app/design/frontend/Packg/themename/Magento_Checkout/templates
>
> - success.phtml
> - onepage.phtml

Note: I have also try to add/remove `checkout_onepage_success.xml` file in layout folder.

Comment: What is the path for the `checkout_onepage_success.xml` you added and what is the content ?

Comment: it's same layout file as given in vendor directory